# Apollo Graphql interface - create sharable URL from query

Tags: graphql, apollo

I have a GraphQL API built with Apollo Engine on Node.JS, and this API includes a `/graphiql` endpoint to the graphql playground where I can generate queries like the example below:

```
query {
  canonical(ref: "") {
    id
  }
}
```

My question is: **how can I generate a sharable URL which contains the query above**.
(for example: `htttp://gql-endpoint.com/graphiql?query=...`

The motivation behind this is to generate URLs that, upon request, open the `graphiql` interface and display the query side by side with the response.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, there is actually a very simple solution for this:
**You can copy the query as is in the graphical interface, and add it to the `?query=` query string parameter**.

For example, given the endpoint `http://gql-endpoint.com/graphiql`, the query would look as follows:

> `http://gql-endpoint.com/graphiql?query=COPY_PASTE_YOUR_QUERY_HERE`.

Using the example above, this would look something like:

```
http://gql-endpoint.com/graphiql?query=query {
  canonical(ref: "") {
    id
  }
}
```

Which, when used on the browser, results in an escaped URL, something like:

```
http://gql-endpoint.com/graphiql?query=query%20{%20canonical(ref:%20%22%22)%20{%20id%20}%20}
```